# Where shall we use fifth order or higher order moment?

Tags: moment-problem

I have seen to use moment up to fourth, but in general, the definition of moment tells for larger than four. I am wondering where we should use higher moment than four and what is the intuition towards data analysis as well as in complex networks. We can define as follows:
 $$
   E[(X-E[X])^k]
 $$

I would like to say thanks for answering it.